# Adding JLabel and Displaying it With a For-Loop

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, arraylist, jlabel

I am creating a hangman game using a java gui. I was wondering how to add a JLabel to an array list and to a JPanel. The problem is that the JLabels have to be added according to the length of the word. I don't know how to add a JLabel if it doesn't have a predefined name. The code is below:

```
for(int x = 1; x <= selectedWord.wordLength; x++){
      wordSpacesPanel.add(new JLabel("?  "));

}
```

If you need more than the above code just ask. Any help is appreciated as I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a local JLabel variable in the loop:

```
for(int x = 1; x <= selectedWord.wordLength; x++){
   JLabel localLabel = new JLabel("?   ");
   wordSpacesPanel.add(localLabel);
   labelArrayList.add(localLabel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Will this work if I wanted to find the third JLabel that was printed out, or any JLabel in the ArrayList for that matter?

Comment: @user2280906: a more general question is: can you get the 3rd item in an ArrayList? And: can you iterate through an ArrayList with a for loop? I think that you already know that the obvious answer to both questions is "yes".